# How can i remove shadow around screen from filter blur() in css?

Tags: css, blur

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNjdv.png)

How to delete this shadow around screen ???
Filter blur does this shadow

```
      &::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(11, 11, 11, 0.766), rgba(11, 11, 11, 0.766)) , url('/Obrazek\ 1.jpeg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-color: black;
        filter: blur(20px);
      }
```

I tried using backdrop filter but its not working

Comment: Have you checked that there are no margins set? There isn't really enough code in your question for us to be sure of what is causing this. See if you can provide a runnable snippet - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `backdrop-filter` or negative indent for filter block:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue,yellow);
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 100dvh;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 0;
}

body:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(11, 11, 11, 0.2);
  inset: 0;
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, corporis, eos, eaque ex ad porro provident vel iusto dolor accusamus quo dolore animi odit dolorum vero aspernatur magnam rerum hic optio illum est soluta deserunt maiores in ut. Voluptatibus, quod, et, quae quas asperiores quis id rerum molestias reiciendis exercitationem magnam ipsam iusto atque doloremque recusandae laboriosam eveniet voluptatum cumque ipsum est! Perferendis, cupiditate, architecto a cumque libero nihil ut in modi iste magnam fugit porro nulla cum qui ab!
```